# Perform Multiple transformation in VS Code Snippet (Chaining or Nesting) ath the same time

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to perform the following Scenario in vs code snippet editor:
Variable/Regex/String| format  ===> (variable/regex/string|format)/regex/string |format , and here is an example of what i am trying to accomplish:

```
"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/.*[\\\\\\/](app[\\\\\\/])(.*?)[\\\\\\/][^\\\\\\/]+?$/$2/}"
```

for the previous expression if the relative path was as follows:

```
src\app\dashboard\products\addProduct\page.tsx
```

running the last snippet will produce the following:

```
dashboard\products\addProduct
```

And what i want it to do is to produce the following:

```
dashboard/products/addProduct
```

I mean that i want the snippet to give the same result as previous in addition to replacing every backslash with a forward slash.
I tried something like the following :

```
"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/.*[\\\\\\/](app[\\\\\\/])(.*?)[\\\\\\/][^\\\\\\/]+?$/${2/[\\\\]/\//}/}"
```

but it doesn't work and produced the following result when running the snippet :

```
${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/.*[\\/](app[\\/])(.*?)[\\/][^\\/]+?$/${2/[\]///}/}
```

So , I know the running both transformations in separate lines and using placeholders will give the desired output, but i don't want running the snippet to produce two line of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For result

```
dashboard/products/addProduct
```

use following body string

```
"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(^.*[\\/\\\\]app[\\/\\\\])|([\\/\\\\][^\\/\\\\]+$)|([\\/\\\\])|([^\\/\\\\]+)/${3:+/}$4/g}"
```